# How to read the raw, unrendered contents of a cshtml file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am creating a demo portion for an ASP.Net MVC website. I would like to be able to display the Razor markup of one of the page's partial views by clicking on a button on the page.  To do this, I will have to fetch the Razor markup directly from the cshtml file and pass it to the view via the model.

How can this be done (specifically fetching the raw, unrendered razor markup)?  I have attempted to open up a file stream to the partial view's cshtml file, but the file path to the views is not intuitive to me:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream("{what goes here?}/Views/Demos/SomePartialView.cshtml", FileMode.Open );
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be the Domain?

Comment: Have you tried either ~ or just nothing for `{what goes here?}` ?.

Comment: When accessing a view via the Razor engine, you can use `"~/Views/..."; however that is not a valid file system path so unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `Server.MapPath`:

```
var localPath = Server.MapPath("~/Views/Demos/SomePartialView.cshtml");
```

Comment: I think this is correct. Just one clarification though: you are using `System.Web.HttpContext` rather than the `HttpContext` property of the base `Controller` class?

Comment: @SteveKonves: No, use the HttpContext of the controller. I copied the code from a plain ASP.NET (without MVC) application. Sorry about that.

Comment: You don't even have to use HttpContext inside a controller action, you can just use Server.MapPath without HttpContext.

Comment: @ataravati: Indeed. Improved answer accordingly.